# Java: final field treemap changes size

Tags: java

I have a java code that contains a class TRADE_HISTORY that holds a history of trades.

Class TRADE_HISTORY has a final field named fMapDateOutputPriceRatios that is set in the constructor .  fMapDateOutputPriceRatios is a map between dates and a double array (TreeMap).  In the constructor, the field is assinged to the argurment using

```
fMapDateOutputPriceRatios = new TreeMap<Date, double[]>(aOutputPriceRatioData);
```

The number of dates is obtained using

```
Set<Date> dates = fMapDateOutputPriceRatios.keySet();
```

The size of dates is printed out in the constructor.  The class has only one constructor.

A problem is occurring when a new trade is added.  When a new date is added, the double vector is used, and obtained from

```
 double[] outputPriceRatios = fMapDateOutputPriceRatios.get( aDate );
```

The error occurs because the date is not available.

While trying to debug the error, the size of dates is being printed.

During construction, the size is 1973 elements.

When the error occurs, the size is 1964 elements.

In particular, the date Apr 11, 2011 is not available at the time of the error.

I'm using eclipse and have set a break on the variable fMapDateOutputPriceRatios to break when the field is modified.  It only breaks during the constructor.

Any suggestion on how to determine why the size of fMapDateOutputPriceRatios changes?

The only lines that access fMapDateOutputPriceRatios are

```
TRADE_HISTORY::TRADE_HISTORY(Map<Date, double[]> aOutputPriceRatioData )
        fMapDateOutputPriceRatios = new TreeMap<Date, double[]>(aOutputPriceRatioData); 
        Set<Date> dates = fMapDateOutputPriceRatios.keySet();  // Used to debug error

TRADE_HISTORY::public void addTradeDistribution_0_to_100(Date aDate, ...)
        outputPriceRatios = fMapDateOutputPriceRatios.get( aDate )  // Causes error
        Set<Date> dates = fMapDateOutputPriceRatios.keySet();   // Used to debug error
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the relevant code in one cohesive block instead of unformatted and interspersed with narrative text.

Comment: The code is rather lengthly, but I agree, that more information would be uesful.

Answer (score 3):

A final reference to an object instance *does not make that instance immutable!* It only blocks changing the reference to point to a different object instance. The reference is final--not the state of the object instance it references.

Note that the set of keys returned by `keySet()` is backed by the map. If you remove keys from it, the corresponding mappings are removed from `fMapDateOutputPriceRatios`. Are you modifying `dates` or using it for anything other than debugging?

Comment: Modifying the `dates` Set was my first thought too. From the way the code is presented, I smell someone who usually writes C++ and not Java. `final` in Java IS NOT THE SAME as `const` in C++.

Comment: There were no modifications to the key map.

Comment: Passing a `Map` to the constructor *copies* the mappings so the original won't affect it after construction. The only other ways to remove elements are `remove()` and operations on the the collections returned by `keySet()`, `entrySet()`, and `values()`. You *must* be doing this somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First, important question: are you sure Dates used as keys are not modified anywhere? Date is supposed to be an immutable object, but it still contains legacy deprecated methods letting one to change the key content. That would cause unpredictable consequences to TreeMap, including the ones you described.

Also, make sure all Dates has hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds cleaned to 0.

Now, suppose the Dates are immutable:

You have actually observed the reduction of the key set size, which means the physical modification of the content happens. The only way I know how it can happen is a concurrent access to the map by two or more threads.

TreeMap have to rebuild the tree when new key is added. That is, unlink part of the tree, and re-link it somewhere else in the tree. During that time, if another thread accesses the same structure and does the same, that subtree may get lost, causing reduction in number of keys.

Therefore, as a first step, try to access this field in a synchronized block:

```
synchronized(fMapDateOutputPriceRatios) {
    outputPriceRatios = fMapDateOutputPriceRatios.get( aDate )
}
```

P.S. I actually do not see put() in your code anywhere, but it must be there, **there are no miracles**.

Comment: The OP passes an existing `Map` to `TreeMap`'s constructor. `put()` is not necessary to fill a map.

Comment: I plan to use multiple threads at some point, but it should be running single thread now.  Here is the code from a higher up class. `code`
boolean useThreads = false;
boolean useThreadService = true;
if (useThreads) {
    Runnable worker = new fooWorker(currentConfiguration,   fPortfolio, fFileDirectory);
    if (useThreadService) {
        executor.execute(worker);                                
    } else {
        worker.run();                                
    }
} else {
    fooWorker worker = new fooWorker(currentConfiguration, fPortfolio, fFileDirectory);
    worker.run();
}
`code`

Comment: In the driver class, date/price ratios for input and output are passed to the constructor and a common date set if created.  In the processing function of the driver class, the TRADE_HISTORY is instantiated, and the output date/price map is passed.  Then, in the  processing function, there is a loop over the common dates, and a new trade is created.

Comment: In the driver routine there is a loop over dates that are common to the input and output date/price maps.  At the point where the error occurs, a date is being added to TRADE_HISTORY and that date doesn't exist in the date/price map field in TRADE_HISTORY.  The map field was initialized during construction of TRADE_HISTORY.  However, the date shoud be there, and the date does exist in the map that is present in the driver class, so the code was modified to remove the date/price map from class TRADE_HISTORY, and use the map that is in the driver code, the program runs.

Comment: If I change the code back, to having a date/price map in TRADE_HISTORY, and put the map access in a synchronized block as suggested, then the program aborts, but there is no error or message, just two null statements.  In this case, I don't know how to locate the cause.  I'm running debug in eclipse, and usually that would stop at the cause of the run time error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback.

Moving the date/output price map to the driving function removes the possibility of a problem with date/output price maps.
However, still get unexpected errors.

A static counter was added to the constructor of TRADE_HISTORY to keep track of the number of TRADE_HISTORY constructed.  Also, an integer id was added to the constructor and set equal to the counter, so the id's should be 1, 2, 3....

When the current error occurs, the TRADE_HISTORY id is printed and is zero, which should not occur.  More debugging is needed in the constructor of TRADE_HISTORY instances.  It appears that there is a TRADE_HISTORY being used that was not constructed properly.

If more help is required, a different question will be started.